# I seem to have lost the ability to detach the Chrome (40.0.2202.3 dev-m) webmaster tools

Tags: web-development, google-chrome

I cannot be the only person who has noticed the webmaster tools re-attached themselves to the main window in Version 40.0.2202.3 dev-m. Does anyone else who uses the dev branch know where the feature went?

I don't for a second believe Google intends for all web developers to dock their tools to the window from now on. I must be looking in the wrong place (note that the gear icon doesn't appear to reveal the setting either).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try holding the dock button for one second and see what happens.

Comment: Talk about bad UX design. I'd tried clicking, not holding. Thanks!